# Toying with `titlesec` to maximize text inside a page and fancy features

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, titlesec

This is a follow up to controlling [the gap between footer and body of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510624/controling-the-gap-between-footer-and-body-of-text). Remember, the goal is to max text within a page. To that end, how can I use the `drop` or `wrap` shapes to work using `titlesec` (no examples][2](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/)).  How to set parameters—I guess using `\titleformat`—of `titlesec` such that the first header looks as follows?

> "Gibberish[as long a skip as possible]Ch. 1"?

Finally, how can I reduce the gap between chapter's header and the top of the page?

```
\documentclass[a6paper, DIV=20]{scrreprt}
%\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{lipsum} % Dummy Text
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titleps}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{hyperref}  

\setlength{\footskip}{24pt}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\NewDocumentCommand{\chapterLabel}{}{Ch. \thechapter}
\NewDocumentCommand{\chapterMark}{}{U HAVE TO DEFINE IT!}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setchapterMark}{m}
{%
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\chapterMark}{}{#1}
}

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\NewDocumentCommand{\myheader}
{mm}
{%
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}XR@{}}#1&#2\end{tabularx}
}  

%\newpagestyle{〈name〉}
%[〈global-style〉]
%{〈commands〉}

%setfoot[〈even-left〉][〈even-center〉][〈even-right〉]
%{〈odd-left〉}{〈odd-center〉}{〈odd-right〉}

\newpagestyle{main}
{
  \setfoot{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}
  {}
  {\chapterLabel}
}  

\newpagestyle{special}
{
  \setfoot{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}
  {}
  {\chapterMark}
}  

%\titleformat{〈command〉}[〈shape〉]{〈format〉}{〈label〉}{〈sep〉}{〈before-code〉}[〈after-code〉]

%\pagenumbering{gobble}
\pagestyle{main}
\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{empty}
% \titleformat{\chapter} % command
% [drop]%hang|block|display|runin|leftmargin|rightmargin|drop|wrap|frame
% {}% format
% {\chapterLabel}% label
% {}% sep
% {}% before code
%  [〈after-code〉]

\begin{document}
\title{Lorem Ipsum}
\author{Dolor S. Amet}
\maketitle

\chapter{Gibberish}

\lipsum[1-2]

\clearpage
\pagestyle{empty}
\setchapterMark{\faBook}
\pagestyle{special}
%\chapter*{\chapterMark~Bibliography}
\chapter*{\myheader{Bibliography}{\chapterMark}}
Let's make that ....

\newpage

... span a second page

\end{document}
```

[image: Shot 1]

[image: Shot 2]

[image: Shot 3]

Comment: To reduce the gap between ths chapter heading and the top of page, you have  the `\titlespacing*` command.  However, there might be conflicts using titlesec with a koma-script document class.

Comment: You should be aware of the fact that `titlesec` and KoMa classes don't go along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution with the standard `report` class and, of course `titlesec` (I had to replace `fontawesome`, which isn't installed on my system, with `fontawesome5`):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a6paper, margin=20pt, bottom=34pt, footskip=24pt, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{lipsum} % Dummy Text
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\NewDocumentCommand{\chapterLabel}{}{Ch. \thechapter}
\NewDocumentCommand{\chapterMark}{}{U HAVE TO DEFINE IT!}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setchapterMark}{m}
{%
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\chapterMark}{}{#1}
}%

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}

\newpagestyle{main}{%
  \setfoot{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}{}{\chapterLabel}
}%

\newpagestyle{special}{%
  \setfoot{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}{}{\chapterMark}
}%

\titleformat{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{empty}\sffamily\Huge}{\rlap{\makebox[\textwidth][r]{Ch. \thechapter}}}{0em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-5ex}{4ex}

\pagestyle{main}

\begin{document}

\title{Lorem Ipsum}
\author{Dolor S. Amet}
\maketitle
%
\chapter{Gibberish}
%
\lipsum[1-5]

\chapter{More Gibberish}
\lipsum[6-12]
\clearpage

\setchapterMark{\faBook}
\pagestyle{special}
\chapter*{Bibliography}
Let's make that
\newpage
... span a second page

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you explain `rlap` and how you would modify it for font size, say, `\large`?

Comment: `\rlap` is a TeX primitivewhich places a box at the right of the insertion point, but doesn't move the latter after the box, as though this box had no width. There exists a symmetric `\llap` command. To modify the font size, you just replace `\Huge` with `\large` in the second argument of `\titleformat`.

Comment: I know how to modify the font size, but it throws off the rest.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Have a look here: https://imgur.com/meHCdTL. Also, why is `rlap` is needed here? It seems as though it's a bit of a hack.

Comment: I see. You have to adjust \titlespacing* for another font size. For `\large`, you can use `\titlespacing*{0pt}{-3ex}{4ex}`. The 2nd argument is the vertical spacing above the heading, the last argument is the vertical spacing below. `\rlap` is used to not have the chapter title *after* the chapter label.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use packages `titlesec` and `titleps` with KOMA-Script classes. They are not compatible (even if the example works with the current versions). So here is a suggestion without these packages:

```latex
\documentclass[a6paper, DIV=20]{scrreprt}
%\providecommand*\Ifstr{\ifstr}% needed up to and including KOMA-Script version 3.27, see https://komascript.de/faq_deprecatedif
%\providecommand*\Ifnumbered{\ifnumbered}% needed up to and including KOMA-Script version 3.27, see https://komascript.de/faq_deprecatedif
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{lipsum} % Dummy Text
\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setlength{\footskip}{24pt}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\NewDocumentCommand{\chapterSymbol}{}{}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setchapterSymbol}{m}
{%
  \RenewDocumentCommand\chapterSymbol{}{#1}%
}

\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ifoot*{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}
\ofoot*{\rightmark}
\renewcommand*\chaptermark[1]{\markright{\Ifnumbered{chapter}{Ch. \thechapter}{\chapterSymbol}}}
\renewcommand*\chapterpagestyle{empty}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myheader}
  {mm}
  {%
    \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{b{##1}}%
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}[b]{@{}Xr@{}}%
      \parbox[b]{\linewidth}{\raggedright#1}&#2%
    \end{tabularx}%
  }

\renewcommand*\chapterformat{Ch. \thechapter}
\newcommand*\originalchapterlinesformat{}
\let\originalchapterlinesformat\chapterlinesformat
\renewcommand\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
  \Ifstr{#1}{chapter}
  {%
    \Ifstr{#2}{}
      {\myheader{#3}{\chapterSymbol}}
      {\myheader{#3}{#2}}%
    \setchapterSymbol{}%
  }
  {\originalchapterlinesformat{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=0pt,afterindent=false,% if you use an older KOMA-Script version replace the line by beforeskip=-1sp
  afterskip=.5\baselineskip plus .05\baselineskip minus .1\baselineskip
]{chapter}

\begin{document}
\title{Lorem Ipsum}
\author{Dolor S. Amet}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Gibberish}
\lipsum[1-2]

\setchapterSymbol{\faBook}
\addchap{Bibliography}
Let's make that ....
\newpage
... span a second page
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

It is also possible to have a chapter title that does not fit in one line:

```latex
\chapter{Gibberish and some more text}
\lipsum[3-4]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I'll fall back on that if I can't find another way, but like the idea of modularity (one package, one purpose), hence toying with `titlesec`. What I'm stuck on right now is getting an A6 layout with non Koma-Script classes.

Comment: Then you should really use a standard class. But note, the usage of many different packages   also enlarges the chance of incompatibilities.

Comment: "enlarges the chance of incompatibilities": not if they are modular.

Answer (score 0):

Because this post was about `titlesec` and I am told it would conflict with `Koma-script`, I'm using a standard class. Putting everything together, here's the closest I get to the spec. `<>` and `()` are just to see how `titleformat` works.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage[
paper=a6paper,
layout=a6paper,
centering,
,left=1em
,right=1em
,top=1em
,bottom=4em
]{geometry}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
%\usepackage[DIV=20]{typearea}% throws off the font
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xparse}

%\setlength{\footskip}{24pt}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\NewDocumentCommand{\myheader}
{mm}
{%
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}XR@{}}#1&#2\end{tabularx}
}  

%titlesec
\titleformat{name=\chapter}
[frame]
{\normalfont\bfseries}
{%
  \filinner
  % \truncchar{left}{2}{\chaptertitlename}. \% An idea...
  \chapterLabel
}
{0.5em}
{\large\filouter \textless #1\textgreater}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}
[frame]
{\normalfont\bfseries}
{%
  \filinner
    \chapterMark
}
{0.5em}
{\large\filouter (#1)}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{*0}{*0}
\NewDocumentCommand{\chapterLabel}{}{Ch. \thechapter}
\NewDocumentCommand{\chapterMark}{}{DEFINE IT!}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setchapterMark}{m}
{%
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\chapterMark}{}{#1}
}
% titleps
\newpagestyle{main}
{
  \setfoot{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}
  {}
  {\chapterLabel}
}  
\newpagestyle{special}
{
  \setfoot{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}
  {}
  {\chapterMark}
}  
\pagestyle{main}
\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{empty}

\begin{document}

\chapter[Intro]{Introduction}

\lipsum

\newpage% \clearpage
\setchapterMark{\faBook}
\pagestyle{special}
\chapter*{Bibliography}
%\chapter*{\myheader{Bibliography}{\chapterMark}}
Let's make that ....

\newpage

... span a second page

%runin
%leftmargin
%rightmargin
%wrap
%frame

\end{document}
```

[image: Shot 1]
[image: Shot 2]
[image: Shot 3]
[image: Shot 4]